# Syntax error with DROP CONSTRAINT within TRY/CATCH

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL:

```
USE [MYDB]
GO
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ContactRole] 
        DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_8bff7074914bc29885004c0a323] 
        GO
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Which gives me this error when parsed:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near 'FK_8bff7074914bc29885004c0a323'.

When alone, or just within a transaction, there is no parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `GO` after the `ALTER TABLE ... DROP CONSTRAINT ..` line

```
....
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ContactRole] 
    DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_8bff7074914bc29885004c0a323] 

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH
```

`GO` is *not* a SQL keyword - it's only understood by SQL Server Management Studio as a "batch separator".

Also: put your `COMMIT TRANSACTION` statement right after the `ALTER TABLE` command - after all, if something does go wrong - the code execution will jump into the catch block right away, so that line is only executed if everything went OK

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't have the `Go` because it indicates the end of the batch and your commit should be right after the alter table.

Also there is no need to check if a transaction is running on the catch because on this situation, it will always have

```
USE [MYDB]
GO
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ContactRole] 
        DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_8bff7074914bc29885004c0a323] 

        COMMIT TRANSACTION; 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH
```